# Bootstrap Modal over the shown

Tags: datatable, bootstrap-modal

The Bug is Chaining Shown Modal

So, i have modal triggering another modal and dismiss the modal before.

Here is the first modal, when i clicked button perusahaan or perorangan, this modal will dismiss and call another modal :
[image]
But the problems is , the modal cannot scrolled down.
[image]

So, the modal shown only half, when i scrolled down it doesnt scroll..
[image]

But, everything is fine if i don't use chaining modals 
Here is the picture again : [image]

Here is the code :

```
<!-- Modal Perusahaan -->
<div class="modal fade" id="Company" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-info">
                <h6 class="modal-title text-white" id="myModalLabel"> Perusahaan </h6>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group has-info">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="comTable"  class="table table-striped b-t b-b">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Nama</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Telephon</th>
                                <th>Fax</th>
                                <th>Alamat</th>
                                <th>Deskripsi</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Batal</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#comTable').DataTable({
        serverSide : true,
        ajax : {
            url     : '{{ this.url.getBaseUri() }}customer/read',
            method  : 'POST'
        },
        columns: [
            {data: "comsName",
                render  : function( data, type, full, meta){
                    return   '<a class="btn btn-info col-md-12 animated pulse" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="document.getElementById(\'protComsId\').value=\''+full["comsId"]+'\'; ajaxProyek('+full["comsId"]+'); document.getElementById(\'unCompanyName\').innerHTML = \''+data+'\'; ">'+data+'</a>'
                }},
            {data: "comsEmail"},
            {data: "comsPhone"},
            {data: "comsFax"},
            {data: "comsAddress"},
            {data: "comsDesc"}
        ],
        order: [[ 1, "asc" ]]
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added delay..

```
function perusahaanShow(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#Company').modal();
    }, 450);
}
```